# $ \int_0^af = 0, \forall a \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a Lebesgue integrable function and $\int_0^af=0, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.Prove that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Here is my solution:

Let $0<a<b$, then $(0,b)=(0,a) \cup [a,b)$ thus $$\int_a^bf= \int_0^bf - \int_0^af \Rightarrow \int_a^bf=0$$

Now we have that $ \mathbb{R}= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}[n,n+1)$ which is a disjoint union, thus $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}f=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_n^{n+1}f=0$$.

Also we know that$$\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}= \{x:f(x)>0\} \cup \{x:f(x)<0\}=\{x:f(x)>0\} \cup \{x:-f(x)>0\}$$.

Now $\{x:f(x)>0\}=\{x:f(x)> \frac{1}{n}\})$ thus $m(\{x:f(x)> \frac{1}{n}\})\leqslant n \int_{\mathbb{R}}f=0$ therefore $m(\{x:f(x)> \frac{1}{n}\})=0 \Rightarrow m(\{x:f(x)>0\})=0$, from the subadditivity of the Lebesgue measure and from the Markov inequality.

With the same argument we can prove that $m(\{x:-f(x)>0\})=0$

Combining these we have that $$m(\{x:f(x) \neq 0\}) \leqslant m(\{x:f(x)>0\})+m(\{x:-f(x)>0\})=0$$

$\therefore$ $m(\{x:f(x) \neq 0\})=0$

$$Second-solution$$

Now $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have in the same way as above that $\frac{1}{2 \delta}\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(y)dy=0 ,\forall \delta>0$.

From Lebesgue's differentation theorem we have that $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(y)dy =f(x)$ almost everywhere.

Thus $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

Are my solutions correct?

This is an exercise I found in a final exam, in undergraduate measure theory.
Although it is a final exam exercise, it seemed to me enough simple,that's why I want to verify my thoughts.

In case I am wrong I would appreciate any help to guide me to a correct solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The inequality $m(\{x:\ f(x)>1/n\})\leq n\int_{\mathbb{R}}f=0$ is true (because ultimately $f=0$ a.e.), but it is likely that the omitted derivation that you had in mind is not correct.

Comment: In your first solution, why is $m(\{ x\mid f(x)>1/n\}) \leq n \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ ? This is not true in general.
Your second solution is better, it is more straightforward, but $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \int_{x-\delta} ^{x+\delta} =0$, (for any integrable $f$), but this value is not necessarily  $f(x)$.

Comment: @Ranc There is a difference between a proposition being true of not and its proof being correct or not. That inequality is true, given the premises.

Comment: There are some typos. In the first solution it should be $$ m(\{  x: f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}) \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f $$ and in the second solution it should read $$ \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\delta} \int_{x-\delta}^{x+ \delta} f.$$ Furthermore, in the first solution you should mention that one similarly proves $m(\{  x: f(x) < 0\})=0$

Comment: @Ranc ..from the  Markov inequality $m(\{f>1/n\}) \leqslant \frac{\int f}{1/n}$

Comment: Thank you i will edit my post

Comment: @MariosGretsas There it is. When you write the argument you can see if it fails or not. For the Markov inequality the $f$ [must be non-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Statement).

Comment: @Peyton it may be true, but the reasoning is lacking, or wrong. To me it looks like $\frac{64}{ 16} = \frac{\not{6}4}{1\not{4}} = \frac{4}{1}$... As you said yourself, Markov inequality requires non-negativity, and this is the inequality OP used.

Comment: @Ranc That is what I said.

Comment: @Peyton..you are obviously correct ,if we take for instance $f(x)=cosx1_{[-\pi,\pi]}$..Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Your first solution is incorrect because Markov inequality only holds when $f$ is non-negative.(Integrals of a function could be negative, but measurement can't) Your second solution is correct. But Lebesgue's differential theorem is a quite strong conclusion. I'm wondering if there's any better solution.

Comment: @XIAODAQU indeed but in case we have $f<0$  then $-f>0$  and i used the Markov inequality in the set $\{x:-f(x)>0\}$  and $-f>0 \Rightarrow \int -f>0$

Comment: @MariosGretsas: Yeah but your inequality should be altered to $m\{f>1/n\}\leq n\int_{\{f>0\}}fdx$. And you don't know whether $\int_{\{f>0\}}fdx$ is equal to 0.

Comment: @XIAODAQU yes but if $f$ is non negative then $m\{f>1/n\} \leqslant n \int_{\{f>0\}}f \leqslant n \int _{\mathbb{R}}f=0$. I proved in my post the the integral of $f$ in the whole real line is $0$.Note that $0 \leqslant \int_{\{f>0\}}f \leqslant  \int _{\mathbb{R}}f=0$

Comment: @Marios Gretsas: $f$ is positive only in $\{f>0\}$, so $n\int_{\{f>0\}}fdx\leq n\int_\mathbb{R}fdx$ is incorrect.

Comment: @XIAODAQU you are right...I have an idea about the first proof: Suppose that $m\{f>0\}>0$ thus exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m(A_{n_0})=m\{f>1/n_0\}>c \geqslant 0$ .We know that  $A_{n_0}$ is measurable thus exists a  $G_{\delta}$ set  $G$ such that $A_{n_0} \subseteq G$ and $m(G$ \ $A_{n_0})=0$. Also from hypothesis the integral of $f$ in every open set is zero because every open set in the real line can be expressed as a disjoint union of open intervals.Now i tried to derive a contradiction using the integral of $f$ on the set $G$ but i couldn't.What can i do with these idea?

Comment: @MariosGretsas: That's a good try. I'll try to complete your proof down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Mario Gretsas 's thoughts. Please help me check if it's correct.

Suppose otherwise then $m\{f>0\}>0\ or\ m\{f<0\}>0$. Without loss of generality, we assume $m\{f>0\}>0$. Since $\{f>0\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\{f\geq1/n\}$, and due to continuity of measurement and integrality of the function we have
$$\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\quad s.t.\quad 0<m\{f\geq1/n_0\}<\infty$$
For the measurablity of $\{f\geq1/n_0\},\exists\ an\ open\ set\ sequence\ \{G'_n\}_n\ $ such that

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n' \triangleq G\supset\{f\geq1/n_0\}\ \ \&\ \ m(G-\{f\geq 1/n_0\})=0\ \ \&\ \ \forall n,\ m(G_n')<\infty$$
Let $G_n=\bigcap_{k=1}^nG'_k$. Then we get a open set sequence $\{G_n\}$ monotonically decresing to $\{G_\delta\}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}m(G_n-G)=0.$

Because of the uniform continuity of integrals, there is a real number $\delta>0$ such that for all measurable set $A$ satisfies $m(A)<\delta$ we have $|\int_Afdx|<\frac{m(G)}{2n_0}(>0)$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}m(G_n-G)=0$, there is a $N$ such that $m(G_N-G)<\delta$.

$G_N$ is open, so it can be expressed as a countable union of open intervals, then $$\int_{G_N} fdx=0$$

But meanwhile, we have $$\int_G fdx=\int_{A_{n_0}}fdx\geq\frac{m\{f\geq1/n_0\}}{n_0}=\frac{m(G)}{n_0}>0$$

Thus $$\frac{m(G)}{2n_0}\geq|\int_{G_N-G}fdx|=|\int_G fdx-\int_{G_N} fdx|\geq\frac{m(G)}{n_0}$$

In contradiction to our hypothesis.

Comment: @XIAODAQU..i deleted the previous comment..your intersection is corect but i think you have to change the index $n$ to $k$ in the intersection..

Comment: @MariosGretsas: Yeah you're right. I've changed that.

Comment: to deduce this equality: $$\frac{m\{f>1/n_0\}}{n_0}=\frac{m(G)}{n_0}>0$$ did you use the fact that for any measurable set $A$ we can find a G delta superset of $A$ such that $m(G)=m(A)$?

Comment: @MariosGretsas: Yes I did. The set $G$ in my deduction is $G_\delta$ set. I need the fact that $m(G'_n)<\infty$, so I wrote the conclusion with $\bigcap G'_n$ instead of writing $G_\delta$ directly.

Comment: @XIAODAQU..how do we know that $m(G'_n) < \infty$ forall $n$?

Comment: @MariosGretsas: Because of the definition of measurement and formation of $G_\delta$. You see, since $m(A)$ is finite, so due to the definition there is a countable union of a sequence of open intervals $\{I_n\}$which satisfies $A\subset \bigcup I_n$ and $m(A)\leq \sum l(I_n)<m(A)+\varepsilon<\infty$. That's how we build ${G_n'}$ and $G_\delta$

Comment: @XIAODAQU..ok then..thanks for your answer..it is a nice proof...I mentioned  in the previous comments that this was a problem in a final exam and now i strogly believe that this problem was ment to be solved with the Lebesgue's differentiation theorem,because it is not easy to come up with such a solution under the pressure of time ,espcially  when the exam has six more problems to solve..

Comment: @Marios Gretsas: Good luck with your exams then.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide a solution that I have not seen from anywhere else.

The result directly follows Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem. Since one can show that the given condition $\int_0^a f =0, \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to $\int_I f =0$ for each intervals $I$ that is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, then for almost every $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we can take $I=B(r,x)$, then based on the given condition, $\int_{B(r,x)} f =0$ for all $r>0$. Thus, when $r\to 0$, by LDT, $f(x)=0$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am referring to the theorem that is proved in Prof. Axler's [Measure, Integration and Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf). This proof shows that to derive Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem, it is not necessary to based on this result. (Theorem 4.10 in Axler's MIRA book is based on Theorem 3.48 which is based on the fourth result of Proposition 3.47 and it's a result can be proved independently, e.g. [using triangle inequality](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-l1-e-normed-linear-space).)

Alternatively, if one uses Folland's book, then firstly, the result directly follows the second form of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theore (Theorem 3.21) as I mentioned above. Secondly, a common proof would be using the fundamental theorem of calculus of Lebesgue integrals (Theorem 3.35 in Folland) which is one of consequences of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem (Theorem 3.21 in Folland).

Answer (score -2):

Take the contrapositive, if $f(x)\neq 0$ a.e. then $\int_{0}^{a} f\neq 0$.

Define the set $E=[0,a]$ (this is the domain of integration), note that we have $\mu(E)$ is non-empty and $\mu(E)=a$, as intervals have measure $b-a$. Now define $F=\{x\in E: f(x)\neq 0\}$. Clearly $F$ has positive measure. Now just use the definition of the Lebesgue integral to conclude: $\int_{E}f d\mu>0$. We have proven the contrapositive of the original statement, so indeed, we can conclude if $\int_{0}^{a} f=0$ $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f=0$ a.e.

You can also try proving it by taking $\int_{0}^{a}f=\int_{0}^{b} f + \int_{b}^{a} f$ by choosing any arbitrary $b$ in $[0,a]$ and arguing by contradiction: if $f\neq 0$ a.e. then the sum of the integrals would not be zero. I haven't worked out the details but I think the argument carries through.

Comment: How can i use the definition?..the definition of the lebesgue integral of a non negative funcion $f$ is the supremum of the integrals of  non negative simple functions that are dominated by $f$.

Comment: The negation of $f=0$ almost everywhere is not $f\ne 0$ almost everywhere. It is enough, that $f$ is not equal zero on a Non-Lebesgue-zero-set.